# Installation of Google Chrome fails in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, google-chrome

I installed the recently introduced Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version directly in my machine and tried installing Google Chrome web browser via Ubuntu Software Installer. I constantly receive the an installation failure message when attempting this.

[image: Error message image link.]

It has to be noted that Google Chrome worked fine in another PC in which I upgraded the Ubuntu version from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

What could be the cause for this issue?

Comment: Edit you question and show What is your failure message?

Comment: Using `apt` would be a lot more fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess the error: `Chrome depends on libappindicator1`.

I ALWAYS get that when installing Chrome. Good news is the fix is simple:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to enable the "universe" repository.

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Once you enable it, update your system and you should now be able to install `google-chrome-stable`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution was to install G-debi package manager in Ubuntu 16.04 and download the .deb file to your home.
then run command

```
    $ sudo gdebi <packagename>.deb
```

and it installed smoothly. There is a GUI way, but I dont know How to use it and running commands is way easier.

Comment: This answer is an alternative method which should fix the OP's situation. It does not answer his question though, which is, "What could be the cause for this issue?"

Comment: Loading Ubuntu store takes longer than it used to. I assume that the OS is not stable about packages